# Custom Combiner is not called

Tags: java, collections

i do some tests on Stream API collect terminal operation.Book says combiner take 2 data collection and merge them.I tested it on TreeSet.Cause of can't see is actually addAll method of TreeSet combiner called or not i created PersonSet.and declared foo and fooAll methods in it.

May be it is not interesting or easy question for you but please help me to understand it better.

I have a Person class:

```
    public class Person {

        private String name;

        public Person(String name) {
            this.name = name;
        }

        public String getName() {
            return name;
        }

        public void setName(String name) {
            this.name = name;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "Person{" + "name=" + name + '}';
        }


    }
```

and

```
    public class PersonSet<T> {

        public PersonSet() {
            System.out.println("PersonSet created");
        }

        public void foo(Person t) {
            System.out.println("PersonSet append Person:" + t);
        }

        public void fooAll(PersonSet<T> t) {
            System.out.println("PersonSet addAll:" + t);
        }
    }
```

and my main class is:

```
    import java.util.function.BiConsumer;
    import java.util.function.Supplier;
    import java.util.stream.Stream;

    public class Main {

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            Stream<Person> s = Stream.of(new Person("1"), new Person("2"), new Person("3"));

            Supplier<PersonSet<Person>> supplier = PersonSet::new;

            BiConsumer<PersonSet<Person>, Person> consumer1 = PersonSet::foo;

            BiConsumer<PersonSet<Person>, PersonSet<Person>> consumer2 = PersonSet::fooAll;

            PersonSet<Person> word = s.collect(
                    supplier,
                    consumer1,
                    consumer2
            );
        }
    }
```

result is :

> PersonSet created
>
> PersonSet append Person:Person{name=1}
>
> PersonSet append Person:Person{name=2}
>
> PersonSet append Person:Person{name=3}

you see there is no "PersonSet addAll:".it means this method was not called

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The combiner is only used when the stream is parallel, and decides to split the work among several threads, in order to combine the results from the two threads.

So you'll need a parallel stream in order to see the combiner in action.